# How to limit the number of characters by range in `yaml` file in netlify-cms Gatsby starter

Tags: regex, yaml, gatsby, netlify-cms

I'm using gatsby and using gatsby-starter-netlify-cms

and I'm trying to add validation for the number of characters in the widget `string`
I have read in the docs that we can use `pattern` with `regex` to implements the validation

and here you can see how they use it

```
fields:
  - label: "Title"
    name: "title"
    widget: "string"
    pattern: ['.{20,}', "Must have at least 20 characters"] // this using regex
  - {label: "Layout", name: "layout", widget: "hidden", default: "blog"}
  - {label: "Featured Image", name: "thumbnail", widget: "image", required: false}
  - {label: "Body", name: "body", widget: "markdown"}
    comment: 'This is a multiline\ncomment'
```

so I tried to do this

```
    pattern: ['.{20,50}', "Must have 20 - 50 characters"]
```

then tried to do this

```
widget: "string", pattern: ['^[\s\S]{20,50}$', "Page Title should be 20-50 characters"]
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
pattern: ['^.{20,50}$', "Must have at least 20 characters"]
```

You can check how it works in [RegExr](https://regexr.com/577ef) (updated with the regex).

Explanation:

- `.`: any character except newline
- `^`: start of string
- `{20,50}`: limit between 20 up to 50 characters
- `$`: end of a string (optional in your case)